ASE EquationOfState error
I am running QE with ASE using Ubuntu WSL and trying to recreate simple case of calculating lattice constant (https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/tutorials/eos/eos.html). Here is part of the code that is producing an error:
a = 4.0  
ag = bulk('Ag', 'fcc', a=a)
traj = Trajectory('Ag.traj', 'w', atoms=ag)
for x in np.linspace(0.95, 1.05, 5):
    run_espresso(ag, 'Ag_lattice', input_data)
    traj.write(ag)
    
    
from ase.eos import EquationOfState
from ase.io import read
from ase.units import kJ

configs = read('Ag.traj@0:5')

volumes = [ag.get_volume() for ag in configs]
energies = [ag.get_potential_energy() for ag in configs]
eos = EquationOfState(volumes, energies)
v0, e0, B = eos.fit()
print(B / kJ * 1.0e24, 'GPa')
eos.plot('Ag-eos.png',show=False)

Note that I set up run_espresso function which executes QE in parallel.
If I run this from WSL I get following error:
/home/mateja/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/eos.py:307: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
  fit0 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(self.v**-(1 / 3), self.e, 3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/PhD/DFT/LatticeConstant/ag_lattice.py", line 87, in <module>
    v0, e0, B = eos.fit()
                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mateja/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/eos.py", line 200, in fit
    return self.fit_sjeos()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mateja/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/eos.py", line 318, in fit_sjeos
    raise ValueError('No minimum!')
ValueError: No minimum!

However, if I after QE calculation run second part of my code from python console I get correct results. What is the difference here between running it from console and from WSL?

I can only think of a single simple answer, is it possible that the traj is being written in a buffered manner and the last point is not present.  That may make the curve fit badly.  I suggest changing things to look like the following.
You also start from the wrong lattice constant at the beginning which will make this issue worse, although if a minimum exists it should still find it.
from ase.eos import EquationOfState
from ase.io import read, Trajectory
from ase.units import kJ
from ase.build import bulk
import numpy as np

a = 4.079 # Fix the lattice 
ag = bulk('Ag', 'fcc', a=a)
with Trajectory('Ag.traj', 'w', atoms=ag) as traj:
    for x in np.linspace(0.95, 1.05, 5):
        run_espresso(ag, 'Ag_lattice', input_data)
        traj.write(ag)
    
configs = read('Ag.traj@0:5')

volumes = [ag.get_volume() for ag in configs]
energies = [ag.get_potential_energy() for ag in configs]
eos = EquationOfState(volumes, energies)
v0, e0, B = eos.fit()
print(B / kJ * 1.0e24, 'GPa')
eos.plot('Ag-eos.png',show=False)

